# Execute second update statement after first's conditions are met

Tags: python, sqlite, transactions

[image]I am trying to implement a bank transaction where one user transfer;s money to another account. But I am facing issue with my sql statements. 
I have declared a condition to check whether the amount being transferred is less than the balance. If the condition is met then only I am updating the table. But my second table which updates the receiver's account gets updated even when the values in the sender's account don't change at all. Here's the code I'm using:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('Bank.db')
con.isolation_level = None
con.execute("begin")
cursorObj = con.cursor()

amnt = 120000
acc_no = 123456


try:
    cursorObj.execute("UPDATE transfer SET balance = balance - (?) where (account_no = (?) and balance > (?))", (amnt, acc_no, amnt))
    cursorObj.execute("UPDATE transfer SET balance = balance + (?) where account_no = 847425", (amnt, ))
    cursorObj.execute("commit")
except con.Error:
    print("failed!")
    cursorObj.execute("rollback")

cursorObj.execute("SELECT balance FROM transfer")
result = cursorObj.fetchall()

print(result)
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: I would first check what the balance is, and only execute both commands if it's larger or equal to the amount sent (using an if statement in your python code)

Comment: Thanks, Nathan. I didn't think about it.

Comment: Glad it helped, I'll post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to first retrieve the balance from the sending user, something along the lines of

```
sending_user_balance = "SELECT balance FROM table WHERE account_no = <account_no>"
```

And only send it if the user balance is equal or greater to the amount sent:

```
if sending_user_balance > amount:
    cursorObj.execute("UPDATE transfer SET balance = balance - (?) where (account_no = (?))", (amnt, acc_no, amnt))
    cursorObj.execute("UPDATE transfer SET balance = balance + (?) where account_no = 847425", (amnt, ))
    cursorObj.execute("commit")
```

Of course, now you can drop the `and balance >` because you've already checked that.

Comment: now how do I check whether the account number exists in the sql table before updating it?